# Is there a way to configure clang-format to keep nested namespace declarations on the same line?

Tags: c++, clang-format

In the codebase I'm working in, we always declare nested namespaces thusly:

```
namespace foo { namespace detail {

// stuff

} }  // foo::detail namespace
```

I haven't yet been able to find a way to configure `clang-format` **not** to break this out into multiple lines:

```
namespace foo {
namespace detail {

// stuff

}
}  // foo::detail namespace
```

I've played around with the `BreakBeforeBraces` configuration, and I've looked into the new `BraceWrapping` configuration in clang 3.8, both without success.

Is it possible to do this without annotating the code with `// clang-format [on/off]`?

Comment: (In C++17, you can say `namespace foo::detail {`.)

Comment: Would be nice if `clang-format` did that if `detail` was the only thing in `foo`. (That's why I came here)

Comment: clang-format will not rewrite nested namespaces as single complex id with ::, but you can do it yourself, if you can use C++17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

clang-format 6.0 has the "CompactNamespaces: true" option that does exactly what you're asking for. See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that this is a feature that has been considered by the clang-format team, but has been rejected. For additional details, see https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17928.

Comment: Marking the new answer as correct, as this one is obsolete.